# Does LevelDB support java?

Tags: java, database, leveldb

I want to know if LevelDB supports java ?
Where can i get the LevelDB. There are no files under http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni java library which gives you a Java API to LevelDB via JNI.

There is also a Pure Java implementation of LevelDB available at https://github.com/dain/leveldb

Both the JNI wrapped and pure Java implementation implement the same interface classes so it's really easy to switch between the two.

Comment: it only supports embedded mode.

Answer (score 1):

LevelDB currently does not ship with JNI bindings, but you can wrap your own JNI binding around the file db/c.h via SWIG and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try of [leveldb-java](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb-java/). This is a pure Java version of LevelDB.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source, i can say that it doesn't support java.

For the source use `svn checkout http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ leveldb-read-only`

Comment: Is there any project that is based on LevelDB java implementation ?

Comment: if you wanted to use leveldb from java would have to build your own bindings to its C code. i looked to see if some one had already build these but the closest thing i could find was [a leveldb list message](http://groups.google.com/group/leveldb/browse_thread/thread/ac4c7a4c999b1038) in which one person said they played with building bindings with SWIG.

Comment: There is a java library for LevelDB https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni -Informed by Hiram Chirino

Comment: Great, that's a jni binding for leveldb.

Comment: The source location has changed.  It's now at http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/source/checkout (which tells you to do git clone https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/)